# Combining two different columns with a separator

Tags: excel, vba

How do I use vba excel to combine two different columns of data into one column like data in ColumnA and ColumnC into ColumnF and with a separator like a comma. It would be great if i have an inputbox to select the columns to combine and which column the combine result will appear.

For Example:

```
 ColA    ColC    ColF
 Apple   Orang   Apple,Orang
 Pear    Grape   Pear,Grape
```

Comment: You don't need VBA, use the [`CONCATENATE()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010062562.aspx) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want a macro to prompt you for different columns try this:

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim firstCol As String
  firstCol = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter first column: ", Title:="Enter data", Default:="A")

  Dim secondCol As String
  secondCol = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter second column: ", Title:="Enter data", Default:="B")

  Dim resultCol As String
  resultCol = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter results column: ", Title:="Enter data", Default:="C")

  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, firstCol).End(xlUp).Row

  Dim comma As String
  comma = ","","","

  For Each rng In Range(firstCol & "1:" & firstCol & LastRow)
    Range(resultCol & rng.Row).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & firstCol & rng.Row & comma & secondCol & rng.Row & ")"
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: an overkill but +1 for the effort :)

Comment: I tend to do that :-)

Comment: Hi thanks for all the suggestion but what I want was to combine all the data from 2 columns eg. ColA and ColC into ColF with a separator like a comma between the combine data from ColA and ColC. As for the input box so that I could also combine dates from other columns and I want to run on macro for automation. Appreciate anyone could help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Portland Runner. It work.

Comment: If you want it to be a little different then I suggest reposting the question with a little more detail and we'll try again.  If your happy with this one then please mark as accepted answer so the question can be closed.  Thanks.